# My CSS animation doesn't roll

Tags: css, css-animations

I am trying to make a css animation, but it doesn't roll for some reason. Source and example here http://codepen.io/jonasroessum/pen/rLmuc

Comment: it works in safari... whats your browser?

Comment: Works in Chrome. I see some animation. What do you mean by roll?

Comment: Do you want it to roll like a fan?

Comment: I want it to do as it does when you hover infinitely. I previously got an animation to work http://codepen.io/jonasroessum/pen/yiagk but for some reason, this doesn't

Comment: It works on Firefox 17.0 and Opera 12.11, but not on Chromium 20.0

Comment: Incidentally, your HTML is invalid a `ul` is not a valid child of another `ul`, *unless* it's wrapped in an `li`.

Comment: maybe, but that's not my problem :/ , changed in anyways

Comment: oh, i see what you guys mean. well then my problem is that it doesn't work in chrome for some reason